# Eclipse Pydev console output jumbled

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I've upgraded eclipse and now the console output comes jumbled with characters. It seems it does not refresh as the output appears or the scroll moves. How to fix this? Can't do anything, if I move my mouse around, maybe some parts of the screen redraw, otherwise they don't

[image: jumbled console output]

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)
Build id: 20190614-1200
OS: Mac OS X, v.10.12.6, x86_64 / cocoa
Java version: 1.8.0_202

PYDEV - Brainwy Software Ltda   Core Plug-in    7.2.1.201904261721  org.python.pydev.core

Comment: @greg-449 updated with version numbers

Comment: Do you only have that behavior with PyDev? Does the console work well for other editors (i.e.: it doesn't seem like an issue in PyDev, but rather in Eclipse itself...)

Answer (score 0):

Looks a lot like [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=548491). Only your Mac OS version does not match what was yet reported on Eclipse bug tracker.
You could try if your problem is gone in one of the recent [integration builds](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/).